# Demystifying getting started with Clojure / ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am just getting started with learning ClojureScript and am baffled by a number of things, mainly to do with the dev environment. I'd really like to get cracking building a web page but am not very close a few days in.

I am reading some books, I have got `Clojure` and `Leiningen` installed with a `re-frame` `Chestnut` template, the `Clojure` plugin for VS Code, IntelliJ and Cursive up and running.

So I have a few mini questions:

1. Why on earth do I keep reading that you can use React with ClojureScript? React is obviously a JavaScript library.
2. What is js-interop and why would you use it?
3. Why are REPLs so important? If you're targeting the JVM or browser, why bother with a REPL?
4. Do I have to use `lein run` before a REPL will run with updated code?
5. I get this error more than I get code to do anything:

```
user=> (run)
Syntax error compiling at (REPL:1:1).
Unable to resolve symbol: run in this context
```

What does it mean? This is what's stopping me from running `Figwheel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just learning Clojure now with a target of trying ClojureScript later, possibly with React. I have been at this for a few weeks now working through "The Joy of Clojure" (the book) and assorted websites and YouTube presentations and am still not ready to fully know what I am doing (though I have understood lazy evaluation and concurrency support. Yeah!). And I used to do a bit of Scheme ... a long time ago. Actually I have to diversify into just trying some development now because I'm getting downcast; there is a lot to digest.

1. You can use React with ClojureScript because there are ["bindings" for React](https://scalac.io/functional-programming-clojurescript-reactjs-reagent/), allowing React elements to call ClojureScript code. Search for "ClojureScript and React" on Google. But you need to get comfortable with ClojureScript first, then get acquainted with React, possibly with JavaScript basics, then try your hand at this unconventional approach.
2. You use "[javascript-interop](https://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/09/12/clojurescript-javascript-interop/)" if you want to call JavaScript code and use JavaScript data structures from your ClojureScript code. The two sides of this "interop" frontier have somewhat different approaches and philosophy. (A big indication of that is that "[immutable.js](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js)" is even a thing). The same for "[java-interop](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop)".
3. REPLs are important because they allow you enter and run your code immediately. Excellent for testing and experimentation. They are also give an interface to the actually running system, somewhat handing you the facilities of a debugger combined with the possibility to change your code, manually replacing functions, as it runs. This is a "live" approach to development coming from the Smalltalk world, as opposed to the "dead" approach, where cycle between editing, compile everything, running, checking the results, stopping, editing etc. etc. Note that the JVM has its own REPL nowadays. Note that when building the browser application in React, you will immediately be told to perform live debugging from your code editor by connecting it to the Chrome browser. Same goal. Read this: [The REPL and main entry points](https://clojure.org/reference/repl_and_main). Read this: [Progamming at the REPL](https://clojure.org/guides/repl/enhancing_your_repl_workflow). Check out some YouTube videos, maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P76Vbsk_3J0). Experiment by starting the REPL and typing code in directly.
4. You can run the REPL directly provided by Clojure (start `clj`) or the REPL provided by Leiningen (start `lein repl`), which is the REPL of Clojure with extras. There is probably a REPL for ClojureScript on Node.js, too. You can enter code directly or load it from a file using `(load-file "file")` for example.
5. It means there is no function `run` to run. You have to write it first. `lein run` executes the application inside a "project" directory layout, and will look for function `-main` by default. Read up on Leiningen: [Leiningen Tutorial](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md).

Be patient, this path is arduous and demands persistence.

Comment: Thanks @David for such a thorough answer - I'm a Javascript developer and wasn't anticipating it to be so much of a 'walled garden` for want of a better phrase. I have got that book too and but have started with 'Clojure For The Brave And True'. Sounds like I really need to get my head round this REPL business!

Comment: Mind blown @ bindings for React!

Comment: I'm probably missing a lot of good tips here. For myself, I have started a personal Confluence Wiki into which I interesting Tips and Code snippets (editing Confluence is yet another thing to learn). You may want to have a code versioning system like git (I still don't understand git, to be honest, that thing is a nasty kraken). Leaf through an intro like "Clojure for the True and Brave" (more books here: https://clojure.org/community/books) Then you need to set up and get used to an editor with REPL integration (currently I use vim and copy-paste as needed; works for now; upgrade later)... .

Comment: @tommmmmmmy Yeah, when I'm done with "Joy of Clojure", I will switch to "React in Action" to get a feel of this and will probably do some JavaScript exercises before switching to ClojureScript. I have no hope for doing this before end-of-year though, especially as I also wanted to take a look at [Datomic](https://www.datomic.com/). Oh God.

Comment: Oh I forget: Absolutely learn how to write unit tests using https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html once you have mastered the trick of declaring namespaces and pulling libraries into your own code for use: https://8thlight.com/blog/colin-jones/2010/12/05/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns.html

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much 